# bundles not working in debug mode Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundles

While in debug mode bundling is not working, unlike release mode.

Error:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)"

ideas?

Code in RegisterBundles:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Comment: Hi, in your BundleCOnfig file do you have a line that looks like this : BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

Comment: yes, but : BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false if DEBUG and when i removed it bundling works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your Bundle.Config file..

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```